# Task Scheduler XML InteractiveToken Always Ignored No Matter What

Tags: windows, scheduled-tasks, xml, windows-task-scheduler, task-scheduler

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<Task version="1.2" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/windows/2004/02/mit/task">
  <RegistrationInfo>
    <Date>2020-10-04T18:42:36.908508</Date>
    <Author>desktop\user</Author>
    <URI>\AAAAAAA</URI>
  </RegistrationInfo>
  <Triggers>
    <LogonTrigger>
      <Enabled>true</Enabled>
    </LogonTrigger>
  </Triggers>
  <Principals>
    <Principal id="Author">
      <UserId>my id</UserId>
      <LogonType>InteractiveToken</LogonType>
      <RunLevel>HighestAvailable</RunLevel>
    </Principal>
  </Principals>
  <Settings>
    <MultipleInstancesPolicy>IgnoreNew</MultipleInstancesPolicy>
    <DisallowStartIfOnBatteries>false</DisallowStartIfOnBatteries>
    <StopIfGoingOnBatteries>true</StopIfGoingOnBatteries>
    <AllowHardTerminate>true</AllowHardTerminate>
    <StartWhenAvailable>false</StartWhenAvailable>
    <RunOnlyIfNetworkAvailable>false</RunOnlyIfNetworkAvailable>
    <IdleSettings>
      <StopOnIdleEnd>true</StopOnIdleEnd>
      <RestartOnIdle>false</RestartOnIdle>
    </IdleSettings>
    <AllowStartOnDemand>true</AllowStartOnDemand>
    <Enabled>true</Enabled>
    <Hidden>false</Hidden>
    <RunOnlyIfIdle>false</RunOnlyIfIdle>
    <WakeToRun>false</WakeToRun>
    <ExecutionTimeLimit>PT72H</ExecutionTimeLimit>
    <Priority>7</Priority>
  </Settings>
  <Actions Context="Author">
    <Exec>
      <Command>C:\Windows\System32\notepad.exe</Command>
    </Exec>
  </Actions>
</Task>
```

If the above script won't run you can make your own script and change the `<LogonType></LogonType>` from `Password` to `InteractiveToken`. I load the script with

```
schtasks.exe /create /RU "user" /RP "mypassword" /TN "Admin OnLogon Script" /XML "sfsdf.xml" /IT
```

What I am trying to achieve is for the task to `Run only when user is logged on` (InteractiveToken). But no matter what I do it is always set to `Run whether user is logged in or not`.

Is this a windows bug?

Answer (score 0):

I have reproduced this, and I think it is a bug, because:

- if you only supply `/RU` in your command, it will then ask you for the run-as password, and then you can see that the task gets created with "Interactive token" as it should.
- the doc say that the purpose of `/RU` and `/RP` is (just) to set the run-as user and the password, not to change the Interactive/notInteractive token. The command should work even without you supplying `/IT`, because that token is already in the XML.

By the way, same problem is with `schtasks /change`.

The workaround for me has been to omit `/rp` in your command and, in case giving the password at the prompt is not an option, and use redirection of input `<` from a file storing the password, at end of your command.